# Flying from Montevideo to Tel-Aviv via Madrid - do I have to go through customs and Immigration in Madrid?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, europe

I am planning a trip to Tel-Aviv - the cheapest and fastest connection is via Madrid - but I also read of 2 hour long lines on airports of people going through passport controls, there was a story of a London airport where 2 hour waiting lines are the average, if I need to go through customs and immigration on this International Connecting flight, in the past I would go straight to the area for International connecting flights - now I am not sure ?  If, I need to go through passport control, do I need to plan for more time?

thanks

Chatos

Comment: It will all depend on exactly which airlines you use, whether you're booked through on a single ticket, and which terminals your flights arrive at and depart from at Madrid. There's not enough information in your question to give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [Madrid–Barajas Airport web site](https://www.aeropuertomadrid-barajas.com/eng/flight-connections.htm) gives detailed information on how to manage the connection.

> Passengers who have to take another flight and/or continue with another airline company (passengers in transit), may need to change terminal due Adolfo Suarez Madrid-Barajas airport has two large hubs, one at the terminal T4, and another at terminals T1, T2 and T3.
>
> Time required to reach connecting flights varies depending on the route, the airline, whether you need to pick up your luggage if not checked to destination, or you must change terminal.
>
> Note that if you do not have a boarding pass for your next flight and/or you have to need to pick up your luggage that is not checked to destination, you must leave the boarding area, pass through immigration controls if any, and make a new check-in to your airline check-in counter. Then you will need to pass through security checkpoints to re-enter the boarding area.
>
> Keep in mind you should add additional time to this process if you must to change terminal.
>
> Passengers in transit without their next boarding pass, and/or have to need to pick up their checked luggage that is not checked to destination, they have a 24 hours [free shuttle bus service](https://www.aeropuertomadrid-barajas.com/transportation/connections-between-terminals.htm) connecting T1, T2, T3 and T4 terminals from the outside. Access to T4S can only be done from inside the boarding area of terminal T4.
>
> For passengers in transit who already have their boarding pass and baggage checked to destination, the connections between terminals can be made as follows:
>
> - From terminal T1 to T4 SATELLITE through a free bus service connecting baggage claim hall 1 terminal T1 and terminal T4 Satellite.
> - From terminal T1 to terminals T2 - T3 through a free bus service connecting baggage claim hall 1 and baggage claim hall 2 terminal T1, and baggage claim hall 6 terminal T2. This connection can walking be done, through security checkpoints, and takes around 10 minutes.
> - Connections between terminal T4 and Terminal T4 SATELLITE must be done by automatic underground train (APM).
>
>   Check the estimated connection time and details about [connections between terminals](https://www.aeropuertomadrid-barajas.com/transportation/connections-between-terminals.htm) at Adolfo Suárez Madrid-Barajas airport.
>
> Connections between terminals T1, T2 and T3 can walking be done, and takes around 10 minutes
>
> Airlines with information desks in the boarding area for connecting flights
>
> - Air Europa: Terminal T2, floor 1; Terminal T3, floor 1
> - American Airline: Terminal T4 Satellite, floor 1.
> - El Al: Terminal T4 Satellite, floor 1.
> - Emirates: Terminal T4 Satellite, floor 2.
> - Grupo LATAM: Terminal T4 Satellite, floor 1; Terminal T4 Satellite, floor 2.
> - Iberia: Terminal T4, planta 1; Terminal T4 Satellite, floor 1; Terminal T4 Satellite, floor 2.
>
> Any question, please ask at Aena information desks (staff wearing green jackets) about information and directions to your connecting flight.